# Consultar valor dentro de uma variável

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se tem como usar o php para fazer o seguinte digamos que tenho um valor dentro de uma variável

$texto = "aqui fica o valor do texto do membro"

Dentro do valor desta variável gostaria de consultar somente a palavra especifica no caso em questão a palavra membro caso ela exista o resultado fique verdadeiro caso ela não exista o resultado fique como falso tem como fazer isso com uso do php ?

**Atualização 02/06/2015:** Desde já agradeço pela ajuda só que estou agora com mais um problema utilizei ambas as respostas para fazer o seguinte coloquei essas urls **https://cloud.mail.ru** e **https://my.pcloud.com** delas fiz uma busca da palavra **pcloud** na primeira e **cloud** na segunda o problema e que esta apresentando conflito ou seja se tiver a url https://my.pcloud.com.

Ai se eu estiver procurando **cloud** da resultado verdadeiro sendo que era para dar falso no texto **pcloud** tem alguma forma de complementar ambos esses códigos das respostas para que faça a consulta da palavra de forma exata o seja verificando do inicio da palavra consultada ao final dela para evitar essa especie de erro ?

Literalmente o erro so não se manisfesta se a ultima letra da palavra for diferente e não a primeira letra.

Comment: primeira resposta da página meu querido:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019169/how-can-i-check-if-a-word-is-contained-in-another-string-using-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim é possível isso usando expressões regulares, use a [função `preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) que diz se o padrão da *regex* existe na *string* passada como segundo argumento.

```php
function findKeyWord($str, $key){
    $regex = '/'. $key .'/i';
    return preg_match($regex, $str);
}

echo findKeyWord("aqui fica o valor do texto do membro", 'membro');
echo findKeyWord("aqui fica o valor do texto do membro", 'membros');
```

A saída para a primeira chamada é `1` para *true* e a segunda `0` para *false*.

[Exemplo - Ideone](http://ideone.com/jTaPdM)

### Atualização

Para encontrar um valor exato utilize a [âncora `\b`](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/borda.html) - *borda*, ao usá-la você denota os limites da palavra que você quer *casar*, onde ela começa e termina, veja um exemplo:

```
function encontrarValor($texto, $palavra){
    if (preg_match("%\b{$palavra}\b%", $texto))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
$texto1 = "aqui fica o valor do texto do ZZZmembroYYY";
$texto2 = "aqui fica o valor do texto do membro";

$resultado1 = encontrarValor($texto1, "membro");
$resultado2 = encontrarValor($texto2, "membro");

if ($resultado1)
  echo "(membro) foi encontrado em {$texto1} \n";
else 
  echo "Não foi possível encontrar (membro) em ({$texto1}) \n";

if ($resultado2)
  echo "(membro) foi encontrado em ({$texto2}) \n";
else
  echo "Não foi possível encontrar (membro) na ({$texto2}) \n";
```

[Exemplo - Ideone](http://ideone.com/h6eQ19)

Comment: No caso tipo digamos que queira usar isso numa function e queira consultar a palavra membro caso eu use esse código e tenha a palavra membros no plural ele ira saber definir que só quero somente membro no singular ou seja se for realizar a consulta neste caso se a consulta for membro no singular e estiver no texto em questão como membros o resultado ira dar false ?

Comment: No caso ele da 1 para verdadeiro e 0 para falso certo ? Ai se eu quiser aplicar isso com uso de  if terei que por se for = 1 verdadeiro e  < 1 falso ne puxando da função findKeyWord colocando ela dentro de um if certo ?

Comment: Não, o php interpreta alguns valores como false, como zero, string vazia, null. Não precisa comparar se é maior que 1. @Rodrigo

Comment: Agradeço a ambos pelas respostas ambas pelas respostas ambas irão ser muito uteis para mim.

Comment: @rray Dei uma de enxerido e editei a tua resposta, para responder o que foi perguntado na atualização da pergunta, qualquer coisa você pode revertê-la ou melhorá-la. =)

Comment: @Rodrigo Veja a atualização da resposta.

Comment: Ok grato pela ajuda não acho que foi enxerido pois você só quis ajudar.

Comment: @qmechanik, q edição bacana :D, obrigado. eu achei q vc ia responder essa pergunta com regex, ja vi outras respostas q vc usa regex, são bem bacanas.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a [função `strpos`](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php).

```
$texto = 'aqui fica o valor do texto do membro';
$procurar = 'membro';
$pos = strpos($texto , $procurar);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "A string {$procurar} não foi encontrada na string {$texto}";
} else {
    echo "A string {$procurar} foi encontrada na string {$texto}";
    echo " e existe na posição {$pos}";
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](https://ideone.com/9m409a)

Para fazer isto de modo que não diferencie maiúsculas de minúsculas, use [`stripos()`](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stripos.php).

Para retornar verdadeiro ou falso, se um valor existe em um texto, faça:

```
function consultarValor($texto, $procurar){
    $pos = strpos($texto , $procurar);
    if ($pos === false)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
}

$texto = 'aqui fica o valor do texto do membro';
$procurar = 'membro';

if (consultarValor($texto, $procurar)){
    // Fazer algo aqui caso $valor existe em $texto.
} else {
    // $procurar não existe em $texto.
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](https://ideone.com/jGb7YB)

Answer (score 2):

Verifique a função **[mb_stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php)**

Funções **mb_*** são funções da biblioteca [MBSTRING](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php), são funções que provêem suporte a caracteres multibyte.

A letra "**i**" no nome da função, indica "*case **i**nsensitive*"

A função retorna a posição da primeira ocorrência da string dentro do texto e, caso não encontre, retorna booleano `false`